# Emacs: query-replace, regular expression, reuse of search result

Tags: regular-expression, emacs, search, elisp

How do I combine something like `query-replace` with a regular expression search-and-replace that in part reuses the search result?

In my case, how to transform

> The programmers are "sort of" confident that the subroutines "load_students" and "compute_student_grade" are without bugs.

into

> The programmers are "sort of" confident that the subroutines \texttt{load_students} and \texttt{compute_student_grade} are without bugs.

I could use two `query-replace` and then hammer yes and no, but it seems sluggish for a big document. Also, I thought about including the whitespace in the searches (one  `"` and one `"` , but that would not work in cases such as `... that's not the way to use "load_students", rather ...`

Is there built-in stuff for this or do you write Elisp code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `query-replace-regexp` thus:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp RET
\"\([^[:space:]]+\)\" RET
\\texttt{\1} RET
```

The query string can be read as: match a sequence of one or more non-space characters into match group 1 (the parentheses are for grouping), all this enclosed by quotes.

The `\1` on the replacement string inserts the match grouping.

The double backslash before `texttt` is for escaping the backslash character from interpretation.

If, instead, what you want to match is only multi-word symbols with underscores, then you need to change the match string to something like `\(\w+_\w+\)`

Comment: Wow! Just out of curiosity, why was it necessary to exclude the space characters?

Comment: Don't know; I was just trying to interpret what you were trying to match and what not. Take it as an example only.